# Scrapy Endless Crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have built a crawling spider using Python Scrapy agains a distributor websites. I am just trying to collect all the URLs under that domain and for each page, what URLs are listed under that page. And then probably I want to use Gephi to visualize the network connections for that domain.

(1) ***How is the crawled URL stored(memory or disk) and what will be the crawl limit?*** 
However, the crawler has been running for 4 days I think and it has crawled about 700K pages. 
I know the Scrapy will not crawl the page that it has already crawled but I am wondering: as the number of pages increases, will there be a limit for Scrapy to "remember" which page it has crawled? The crawled URL will stay in the memory or what is the mechanism behind this?

(2) ***Will there always be an end to crawl a single domain? What if not?***
BTW, should I stop crawling right now since I don't know when will be the end of this spider, I don't know if it would be possible that they have some dynamic page so "domain crawling" is actually an endless task.... for example, they have some parametric search box and all the combinations of those search will lead to a new page(javascript call) but actually.. that lead to a huge redundancy..

Before I know Scrapy, I tried to figure out the pattern in the URL first and then populate all the URLs, after that, go to each URL and using urllib2+bs4 to scrape. So I am not quite sure this kind of "blind" crawling is actually controllable.

There might be some "philosophical" questions here instead of specific questions but... Appreciate any thought or idea.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?  If Scrapy keeps a history?

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is indeed one of the questions, they keep the crawled URLs in memory or what?

Comment: According to [the overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html), you are responsible for storing the scraped data.  The overview (and its associated pages) explain how to do it.

Comment: How do i use scrapy to do "scheduled" crawling? What i mean is, i don't want scrapy to run continuously, i want it run for lets say 1K urls crawled, then take a break and restart. Should I even be worried about scrapy taking pauses? Another thing, if scrapy crawling fails for some reason, how do i restart from where it left off? does it do it automatically? Or do i have to restart from scratch again ?